# Print filename and the file modify date from the output of hdfs dfs -ls command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am tring to print the filename and its modification date on HDFS,  the problem with hdfs is it doesnot support ls -l command, so when i use 
`hdfs dfs -ls /directory_path`  here is the sample output

```
Found 6 items
drwxr-xr-x - dps12 supergroup 0 2013-08-14 05:10 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/201
drwxr-xr-x - dps12 supergroup 0 2013-08-15 05:13 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/201
drwxr-xr-x - dps12 supergroup 0 2013-08-16 05:15 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/203
drwxr-xr-x - dps12 supergroup 0 2013-07-30 20:32 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/204
drwxr-xr-x - dps12 supergroup 0 2013-07-31 22:54 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/205
drwxr-xr-x - dps12 supergroup 0 2013-08-13 04:15 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/206
```

the output i need is

```
2013-08-14 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/201
2013-08-15 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/201
2013-08-16 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/203
2013-07-30 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/204
2013-07-31 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/205
2013-08-13 /data/PSG/LZ/FORECAST/206
```

i know for experts this must be a no brainer,  any help or pointers how could i achieve this would be of great help..

i have thought of using

```
hdfs dfs -ls /directory_path | while read line ; do $line|awk 'print $4  $6' ; done;
```

but it wasn't of anyhelp

Comment: 1. You missed a `echo` before `$line`

Comment: 2. Your fields are wrong: `awk '{print $6" "$8}'`

Comment: Thanks devnull the actual issue was the echo command, because of which   it was giving errors, Thanks :)

Comment: @DPS, any specific reason you want use the while loop?

Comment: @JtheRocker no no specific reason, i am new with scripting so didn't knew awk would work directly on the output of ls

Comment: no problem mate! We all are here to learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try with awk -

```
hdfs dfs -ls /directory_path | grep -v 'Found' | awk '{ print $6,$8 }'
```

`grep -v 'Found'` is for ignoring the `Found x items` line at the beginning.

Thanks to psny for that.

Comment: Just note that awk is still accessing the first line "Found 6 items", so in case you also wanted the second column, you'd have to remove the first line. One method would be to do 'grep -v Found' before the awk statement.

Comment: @psny: Thanks forgot about that. Added!